# Drone.io auto_tag with branch name

Tags: drone.io

Using the drone docker plugin in order to create my cloud images, I would like to simplify the workflow by having drone automatically tagging my images depending of the git branch name I'm working with.

I saw a auto_tag but unfortunately it always tag my images as "latest".

```
###
 # Tag deployment
 # Docker image
###
push-tag-news:
  image: plugins/docker
  registry: docker.domain.com:5000
  secrets: [docker_username, docker_password]
  repo: docker.domain.com:5000/devs/news
  auto_tag: true # Or how to specify the current branch for the tags: option?
  when:
    exclude: [master, dev]
```

has anyone tried to do something similar?

I'm using drone 0.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `auto_tag` uses the repository/git tags seems to me you are looking to set custom docker image tags.

You can use any of these variables http://docs.drone.io/environment-reference/

Try using `DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH`

```
  build-docker-image:
    image: plugins/docker
    repo: myname/myrepo
    secrets: [ docker_username, docker_password ]
    tags:
      - ${DRONE_COMMIT_BRANCH}
      - latest
```

Comment: I don't know why but I wasn't able to fully understand their doc. Thanks a lot!